# Access SWF Method From Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, methods, state, swfloader

I have hit a brick wall after trying almost every example I have come accross. I was hoping that someone here might be able to help me.

In a nutshell I have a Flex parent which is embedding a Flash SWF file which has a Method which needs to be accessed from Flex.

MXML:

```
    <mx:states>

        <mx:State name="intro">
            <mx:AddChild position="lastChild">
                <mx:SWFLoader x="285" y="170" id="introSwfLoader" source="@Embed(source='Introduction.swf')" />
            </mx:AddChild>
        </mx:State>
```

I have tried strong typing the SWFLoader as a MovieClip to gain control of it but have had no luck.

Flash:

```
function reset(){

    // some code
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Essentially all I need to do is reset/reload the Flash SWF when the mx:State changes.

Thanks for your time..

Comment: Have you tried setting up and using a LocalConnection to communicate between the two SWFs?

Comment: I think you should quantify what "No luck" means.  Are you getting a runtime error?  A compile time error?  Does nothing happen?  Or does something happen?  If something happens, what is it?  And why is it different than what you expected?

Comment: different scenarios had different outcomes. I have not tried LocalConnection as I was under the impression this was for AS2? I`m currently using AS3.

Comment: This was my last attempt..     
var introSwfMc = introSwfLoader.content as MovieClip;
introSwfMc.reset();

Which returns, 
Error #1069: Property reset not found on air__embed_mxml_Introduction_swf_243329398 and there is no default value

Sorry for being so vague. But I have tried ALOT of different approaches. Eagerly awaiting your reply.

Comment: LocalConnection works great w/ AS3 [and I believe AS2].  Beyond that, you should document all the scenarios you tried in the question, and be sure to include why they didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I`ll give localConnection a try.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need LocalConnection.

Try this - it's not the most elegant solution but this seems to work - in some method in your Flex app, you can access the loaded SWF as a MovieClip this way:

```
function accessLoadedSWFAsMovieClip():void{
    var container:DisplayObjectContainer = introSwfLoader.content as DisplayObjectContainer; //gets the SWFLoader content as a DisplayObjectContainer
    var loader:Loader  = container.getChildAt (0) as Loader; // gets the first child of the DisplayObjectContainer, which is a Loader (not sure why)
    var mc:MovieClip = loader.content as MovieClip; //access to the main timeline of the Loader's content (cast as a MovieClip, because we can then call ambiguous functions with no errors. I assume if your loaded swf had a document class you could cast it as the document class here)
    mc.reset(); // call the function inside our loaded SWF
}
```

Comment: Very different from my original answer but I tested this quickly and it definitely works :)

Comment: ...bump - did you figure this out?